# Arrays attempting to re assign them via = using indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

This seems basic but it won't do as I imagined this is from console:
I declare a string str (so as to play with the string)

```
str = "my name is burt"
"my name is burt"
str
"my name is burt"
words = str.split(" ")
(4) ["my", "name", "is", "burt"]
```

// I make an array using the split method

```
words[0][0]
```

// I check that I can use indexes to look at it
"m"
// Attempt to change it?

```
words[0][0] ="n"
```

"n"
// Here is the problem I try to change the value via assignment but it 
// wont allow it the m has not changed to an "n"
words

```
(4) ["my", "name", "is", "burt"]
```

// but I can change it like this

```
words[0] = "ny"
```

//  why can i not reference the my via the second index

// but i can log it

```
console.log(words[0][0]);

 n
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. Plain and simple.

Comment: True -- and I've always found it weird that JavaScript doesn't throw a useful error when you try to mutate them. It sort of pretends that it did something when nothing actually happened. In python doing something like `words[0][0] = "ny"` will at least tell you that you can't do what you are trying to do: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result you can convert the string to an array, convert back to string if necessary

```js
const str = "my name is burt";

let words = [...str];

words[0] = "n";

// convert to string    
words = words.join("");

console.log(words);
```